# Appending / Adding function to existing jqueryui DatePicker 'onSelect' event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Im trying to append or add a function to the existing call stack for jqueryui's datepicker 'onSelect' event, but am failing miserably.

Ive pasted an example of what im trying to do here.

Basically, it should `alert('abc')`, then `alert('def')` after the first datepicker selection has been made.

http://jsfiddle.net/cfE7w/

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you called this

```
$('#hello').datepicker("option", "onSelect", function(){
    var prevFunction ...
```

the current event handler is already the new one! So when the event fires and the following code executes

```
var prevFunction = $(this).datepicker("option","onSelect");
```

`prevFunction` points to itself. You can solve this using an IIFE:

```
$('#hello').datepicker("option", "onSelect", 
  (function() {
    var prevFunction = $('#hello').datepicker("option","onSelect");
    return function(){
      prevFunction();
      alert('def');
   };
 }()));
```

Now `var prevFunction = ..` is called immediately and the old handler is stored. The new handler is assigned with `return function(){ ...`.